# Cant seem to figure out what Sorting Algorithm I have written

Tags: python, sorting

We recently stared doing sorting algorithms in school. So I wrote the code below, it works but I don't know whether it is Bubble sort or Selection Sort.

```
for i in range(0 , len(array)):
  for j in range(0 , len(array) -1):
    if (array[j] > array[j +1]):
      array[j] , array[j + 1] = array[j + 1] , array[j]
```

Comment: This is an inefficient version of bubble sort. In each iteration the highest remaining value is shifted to the end of the array (I.e. it _bubbles_ up). But you do not use the outer for loop at all. After n iterations off the outer loop you know that exactly the last n elements of the array are properly sorted. Thus you could save lots of time by changing your inner loop to `for j in range (0, len(array) - i):` (also i should iterate over `range (1, len(array))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm: **`Bubble Sort`**

Because it repeatedly swaps the adjacent elements if they are in the wrong order.

```
for i in range(0 , len(array)):
    for j in range(0 , len(array) - i -1):
        # traverse the array from 0 to len(array) - i - 1
        # Swap if the element found is greater 
        # than the next element
          if (array[j] > array[j +1]):
              array[j] , array[j + 1] = array[j + 1] , array[j]
```

There is an error in your second for loop, you need to traverse it to `len(array) -i -1`, because at the end of each iteration largest element would be at the end of the array.

*Hope this answers your question!!*